# measure the best prediction method in R for a lot of time series

Tags: r, list, loops, dataframe, time-series

I'm struggling with a problem in R. I want to evaluate the best measure of prediction for a lot of time series with different methods, for example `ME, RMSE, MAE, etc.`

The measured data are stored in a list, which saved these data frames: `ME, RMSE, MAE`... To evaluate the best method I thought about to sum up all values of the different methods and divide them by the length of `residuen_overall`.

For example by the length of two (ME):

(-1+0.26) / 2 --> -0.37

```
residuen_overall[[1]]
#      ME  RMSE  MAE    MPE  MAPE
#naive -1 10.15 3.93 -22.69 40.14

residuen_overall[[2]]
#        ME RMSE  MAE  MPE  MAPE
#naive 0.26 7.84 6.33 -3.1 19.61
```

My idea was to create a loop, but it is not working:

```
methods <- list("ME", "RMSE", "MAE", "MPE", "MAPE")

for(i in 1:length(residuen_overall)) {
  cumsum(residuen_overall[[i]]$methods[i]) 
  }
```

I hope someone can help me, please! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are your data (if you use `dput()` in the future it will make it easier to reconstruct them for testing purposes):

```
residuen_overall <- list(
  c(ME=-1,RMSE=10.16,MAE=3.93,MPE=-22.69,MAPE=40.14),
  c(ME=0.26,RMSE=7.84,MAE=6.33,MPE=-3.1,MAPE=19.61))
```

"Summing up all the values and dividing by the length" is just computing the mean value.

Collect your lists into a matrix:

```
r2 <- do.call(rbind,residuen_overall)
```

Compute the mean of each column:

```
colMeans(r2)
##     ME    RMSE     MAE     MPE    MAPE 
## -0.370   9.000   5.130 -12.895  29.875
```

It's still not clear to me how this is going to help you figure out the best method ...

Comment: It is working!!! Thank you so much. My idea is behind the best method, if you have thousand of different time series and you can calculate all of them by the mean, you can see some deviations between the actual and mean data. But I have to figure that out. Thank you so much!